# Android back problem

Tags: android, android-intent, back

I have three activities, from A it is going to B, from B it is going to C. I am using following code to transfer from one activity to another.

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I want that when I use the back button, it should come to B if it is at C(which is ok for me), but if I use back button at B activity, it should not go to A, it should directly go out the application. How it can be arranged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class A you would put:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This will remove class A from the Activity stack.

Answer (score 3):

There you go

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to remove class A from the stack, rather than keeping it there and never letting the user get to it? Is there a reason to save it?

Comment: True. On the other hand Android OS handles those things very well by itself. The above code gives you full control from within your activity so you don't have to mess with foreign ones. I believe that is more "androidish" and correct in terms of task separation.

Answer (score 2):

call finish();
when you launch the activity B from the activiy A

Answer (score 1):

Override the member function `onBackPressed()` inside your `Activity` class.

Example:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, B.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```